# Invalid input and reprompting

Tags: javascript, dom, while-loop

I'm trying to figure out how to do the following:  The user is allowed to input a value from 1 to 10, while anything under or over that allowable range isn't allowed. What I'm trying to do is, effectively, tell the user they aren't getting enough chocolate or they are getting too much chocolate, then reprompt them again.

I don't know how to do this in JavaScript. Here is the code I have so far:

```
var numberOfPoundsOrdered;
numberOfPoundsOrdered = prompt("How many lbs of chocolate would you like to order?");
while (numberOfPoundsOrdered < 1 || numberOfPoundsOrdered > 10) {
        numberOfPoundsOrdered = prompt("How many lbs of chocolate would you like to order?");
}
```

I'm new to JavaScript. I would like to include the "error message" in the while loop if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var numberOfPoundsOrdered;
while (true) {
  // Make sure numberOfPoundsOrdered is number before the check.
  numberOfPoundsOrdered = parseInt(prompt("How many lbs of chocolate would you like to order?"), 10);
  
  
  if (numberOfPoundsOrdered < 1) {
    // Do something if number too small.
    console.log("Too less chocolate.");
  } else if (numberOfPoundsOrdered >= 10) {
    // Do something if number too large.
    console.log("Too much chocolate.");
  } else {
    // Cond met, leave
    break;
  }
}
```

or do while:

```
var numberOfPoundsOrdered;
var numValid = false;
do {
  // Make sure numberOfPoundsOrdered is number before the check.
  numberOfPoundsOrdered = parseInt(prompt("How many lbs of chocolate would you like to order?"), 10);

  if (numberOfPoundsOrdered < 1) {
    // Do something if number too small.
    console.log("Too less chocolate.");
  } else if (numberOfPoundsOrdered >= 10) {
    // Do something if number too large.
    console.log("Too much chocolate.");
  } else {
    numValid = true;
  }
} while (!numValid);
```

Comment: Or use `do...while`?

Comment: Yep, I'll add an alternative.

Comment: I also figured I could change it to:

while (numberOfPoundsOrdered < 1 || numberOfPoundsOrdered > 10) {
            numberOfPoundsOrdered = prompt("You either wanted too little or too much chocolate, so please try again.  How many lbs of chocolate would you like to order?  (1-10 lbs)");
        }

Comment: Thank you for your help!